# jQueryMobile close dialog WITHOUT page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Though this question is asked previously but their is no workaround suggested. I have a form and on the click of check box I want to open a popup/dialog and want user to enter some data in the popup/dialog, but when dialog/popup is closed my parent page looses all data, as it is reloaded. Can you please help me to achieve same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using SimpleDialog2 http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/
but it is not that advance, gui seems to be distorted on some resolutions.

Answer (score 3):

The popup widget of JQuery mobile will compare current url to the original one and refresh the page if they aren't match. So, if you want to prevent this behavior, you have to avoid the popup widget affecting the history. Just add data-history="false" to your widget.
However I am not sure about dialog widget because it is totally different from popup. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you use data-rel="back", you need to remove it.
After this, I think you need to add this action to the close button on dialog.

```
$('yourButton').click(function(){
    $('yourDialog').popup('close');
});
```

Comment: but what about the pale background that I want to have ...on click of that page automatically reloads

Comment: What do you mean about pale background? In my case, on click the close button of dialog it doesn't automatically reloads.